# Caching objects on httpcontext asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, httpcontext

I'm trying to migrate from .net framework MVC 5 to .net core 2.0 MVC

good old times I can get or set the cached objects by calling

```
HttpContext.Current.Application.Lock();
HttpContext.Current.Application["foo"] = bar;
HttpContext.Current.Application.Lock();
```

but I cant migrated this part of my application to the .net core.

How can I handle this on core 2.0?

Comment: I don’t know what you mean by caching on the context ... but httpcontext in aspnet core has an items property which is also a dictionary, acccessible anywhere the httpcontext is available within the scope of a request ... is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`HttpContext.Current.Application` was a feature that was left in to make applications easier to port over from ASP classic. It has been superseded since ASP.NET 1.0 by `HttpContext.Current.Cache` and since .NET 4.0 by `System.Runtime.Caching`.

However, all of these caching features are now missing from AspNetCore. There is a lightweight caching option, [`IMemoryCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory) that can be used for many scenarios which is similar to `HttpContext.Current.Cache`. For more scalability, there is also a [`IDistributedCache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed).