# What is equivalent of asp.net cache in .net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I want to share specific data for all users in the .net core system same we are doing in MVC5

I checked InMemoryCache and used it to save data but Unfortnality, this share data individually per user

What I mean in MVC 5 if I used

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache["xyz"] = "Test Value"
```

and second user logged in and called

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache["xyz"]
```

the new user will get the result "Test Value"
and if he changed this value for other value the first one will see this changes

but in .net core using InMemory Cache I can't find any option to share data between system users

```
_cache.Set("xyz","Test Value);
```

Other users will not able to retrieve the value for xyz key

I am setting the InmemoryCache value in startup

Comment: The [in-memory cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1) is application-wide, not per user.

Comment: I haven't tested, from a quick search I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461484/caching-objects-on-httpcontext-asp-net-core?rq=1
He talks about Cache in-memory (more limited): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-3.1
And distributed caching (scalable, but you have ot be opened to work with a database...): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: @poke  i tested multiple time i am not able to share data between users

Comment: Using DI in constructor

Comment: Hey @AYKHO, as @poke already mentioned, the `IMemoryCache` is application-wide,  what do you mean by different user?

Comment: @ShaharShokrani I am setting the value for IMemoryCache in startup but in actionfilter i am not able to see this value

Comment: Can you provide the code?

Answer (score 0):

If multiple Users (threads) tries to access the `IMemoryCache` resource at the same time, than you should use lock in order to handle its access.

Otherwise the second user will see no result within the cache.

Here is great [article](https://sahansera.dev/in-memory-caching-aspcore-dotnet/) with a `Semaphore` handling the `IMemoryCache` service.